# Question about last part of proof with principal curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry

The follwoing task and solution were given:

> *Let $S\in\Bbb R^3$ be a parametric surface, $p\in S$.*
>
> *Proof : if $\kappa(p)<0$, than each neighbourhood of $p$ in $S$ hit both sides of the affine tangent plane.*

Solution:

*Let $\kappa(p)<0$, than the principal curvatures have got different signs.
Let's take $\kappa_1(0,0)<0$ and $\kappa_2(0,0)<0$.*

*We know that $S$ is the graph of a function f, near $p$.*

*Now we can say that near $p$ the function $f$ alongside the $e_1$-axis is negative and alongside the $e_2$-axis is positive. So each neighbourhood  of $p$ in $S$ hit both sides of the tangent plane.*

My problem:
Why can we say that near $p$ the function $f$ is negative, alongside the $e_1$-axis and positive alongside the $e_2$-axis  ?

Comment: What is the function $f$?

Comment: @DiegoMath: $f$ is an arbitary function about  the tangent plane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the intention is that we choose our coordinates so that $p \in S$ is the origin (ensuring $f(0) = 0$), the tangent plane at $p$ is horizontal (ensuring $\nabla f(p)=0$) and the principal directions at $p$ are along the $e_1,e_2$ axes. At such a point, the principal curvatures are simply the second partial derivatives $\kappa_1 = \partial_1\partial_1 f, \kappa_2 = \partial_2 \partial_2 f.$

Since $\kappa_1 < 0$, we thus know that the restriction of $f$ to the $e_1$ axis $g(x) = f(x,0,0)$ satisfies the properties $g(0) = 0,$ $g'(0) = 0$ and $g''(0) < 0$, and thus from basic calculus we know that $g(x) <0$ for small non-zero $x$. Similarly along the $e_2$ axis (where the corresponding curvature $\kappa_2(p)$ is positive) we see that $f$ must be positive.